# How to send output of an Eclipse testing code through email using Jenkins. The dynamic output should be inside message body of the email

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, automation, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

My code is to find the 'PromotionHistory' data which is not loaded into the database from the source file after the daily batch job is completed. The batch job loads the new data daily.

I am able to send the email with Pass/Fail Status along with the console output containing the unloaded 'PromotionHistoryIds' as an attachment through Jenkins. But I need the dynamic output inside the message body of the email.

I am not seeing any option in Jenkins to do that. Is it possible or do I need to look for any other way, an alternative to get this done?

Thanks for the help, in advance!

Comment: Please show your `Jenkinsfile`, especially how you get the dynamic output and how you send e-mails in the pipeline.